# What's causing this error in synthesizing and inferred latches warning?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, xilinx, vivado, synthesis

I have two issues with my code:

1. This is the module that's showing an **error** in line 11 `curr_state <= rst_n ? next_state : A;` during synthesis:

```
module moore_det_nonov(input clk, rst_n, x, output reg z);
  parameter A = 4'h1;
  parameter B = 4'h2;
  parameter C = 4'h3;
  parameter D = 4'h4;
  parameter E = 4'h5;

  reg [3:0] curr_state, next_state;

  always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
     curr_state <= rst_n ? next_state : A;
  end
  
  always @(curr_state or x) begin
    case(curr_state)
      A: next_state <= x ? B : A;         
      B: next_state <= x ? B : C;
      C: next_state <= x ? D : A;
      D: next_state <= x ? B : E;
      E: next_state <= x ? B : A;
      default: next_state = A;
    endcase
  end

  always @(curr_state) begin
    z <= (curr_state == D) ? 1:0;
  end

endmodule
```

[image]

2. But if I replace the ternary operator in line 11 to an `if-else` statement as shown below, then it synthesizes the module with no errors but now shows two new **warnings** at line 18, `A: next_state <= x ? B : A;`:

```
  always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
     // curr_state <= rst_n ? next_state : A;
     if(!rst_n) curr_state <= A;
     else curr_state <= next_state;
  end
```

[image]

Comment: Try declaring the `clk` and `rst_n` types: `input wire clk, input wire rst_n`.

Comment: @awjlogan I tried, nothing changed. Besides, i suppose port declarations are of `net` datatype by default if not declared as reg.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to the fact that your `curr_state` logic is not recognized by your synthesis tool as a [synthesizable construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Synthesizable_constructs).  Once you changed the code from a ternary to an `if/else`, it was recognized as a synthesizable pattern.

I don't understand why you get warnings about latches.  The code looks acceptable.

However, combinational logic should use blocking (`=`) instead of nonblocking (`<=`) assignments.  Change all your assignments to `next_state` and `z` to blocking.  For example:

```
  A: next_state = x ? B : A;
```

Since you only have 5 states, your state variables only need to be 3 bits wide, not 4.

Check your tool documentation for the specific warning messages you see.  There may be explanations with code examples that might help you.

You could also try starting from scratch to be sure your software is really working with the version of the code you posted here.  Maybe the software got confused with all the code edits you made.

Comment: Changing the non-blocking assignments to blocking assignments in the case statement gets rid of the latches for me.